# Keep selected text on input focus

Tags: javascript, select, text, input, focus

I’m trying to add a link on a selected text (inside a `contenteditable`). The link window is just an input field. The problem is that after I select some text, click the link button to show the link input field and focuses, I lose the selected text.

How does WYSIHTML5 do it: http://xing.github.com/wysihtml5/ ? If you click on the link icon in the toolbar and focus on the link’s input field, your selected text stays selected.

Alternatively, I could save the selection in a variable, but how do I call it on `blur()`? I have to make the variable global? I‘m getting `“selected not defined”` when on `blur()`.

HTML:

```
<button class="link_button">L</button>
<div class="link window hidden"><input name='link' class='link_input' autofocus='autofocus' value='http://'/></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.link_button').click(function() {
    $('.link').toggleClass('hidden');
});

$('.link_input').focus(function() {
    var selected = saveSelection();
})

$('.link_input').blur(function() {
    restoreSelection(selected);
})

function saveSelection() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            return sel.getRangeAt(0);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        return document.selection.createRange();
    }
    return null;
}

function restoreSelection(range) {
    if (range) {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        } else if (document.selection && range.select) {
            range.select();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If the selection is not disappearing then WYSIHTML5 must either be using an iframe for the editable area (a common technique with WYSIWYG editors; it used to the only way to do it in Firefox in the old days) or faking the selection. I suspect it's the former.

Comment: @Alex It's probably an old question but I am wondering if you have found any solution so far ? I have the same issue! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rangy library](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/source/browse/trunk/src/js/rangy.js?r=5) for easy selection management.

1. This is a cross-browser supported library.
2. Simple to use

Comment: No, I’d like to do it without a library.

Comment: Then check the code in this library. You will get how to get the selection and save it correctly.